# SSO Sign On - How to use a web client for mobile app (Google oauth provider)

Tags: react-native, oauth, google-oauth

I added to my web application SSO Sign on. For example using Google Oauth authentification. I have a Web Client ID with dedicated credentials.
My question is :
-> **Can I use the same Client ID (originally for web app, credentials) for my mobile application using Universal Link as redirect URL to my mobile application ?**

I tried with an iOS client ID, redirection worked well. Problem is that it's using another `Client ID () => ....apps.googleusercontent.com`. I can't deal with severals Client ID, in my usecase, one Client ID should be working, either if it's for a Web App, or a Mobile App. I'm managing to use web client ID and authenticate on an in-app browser on my mobile application. Issue is because it's not an iOS client ID for ex, redirection to the app doesn't work.

Any ideas, suggestions ?